IK constraint moves in the wrong direction - Blender 4.1
I was animating an Airbus a340-600 nose gear.
so to retract the gear there is an arm in front of it that pulls it up, this arm is composed out of 2 parts wich i animated with an IK constraint but can't figure out how to invert rotation direction on the IK constraint [![Needs to go in the arrow direction][1]][1]
[![Actually go in the arrow direction][2]][2]
Blender File:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/jrc8rgxjoo4dk0z/Nose_Gear.blend/file
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/E4DlDobZ.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/bZaNl3TU.png

Blender needs to know in what direction it is supposed to bend the bones, so in Edit mode slightly push the knee in the right direction:

Result:


already tried but didn't worked

I've edited my answer, is it not what you want?

Deso jai fini parr reussir falait peut etre le bouger plus

D'accord, bonne continuation   ;)
